# GUI automation with clicking on text

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, sikuli, gui-testing

There are many GUI automation tools that allow clicking on a specified image (well-known Sikuli, for example). Is there any way to click on the specified text, not image? This way the tool will:

1. make screenshot
2. recognize text on it
3. find text position (somehow)
4. send click event to this position

It would be much easier to write tests using this approach (many interfaces have text button, inputs etc.) rather than make screenshots for every single element.

I've seen some OCR feature in Sikuli but it didn't work for me (I tried invoking click('some-text-here').

Comment: "it didn't work" is worthless diagnostics.  Provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), what you expected it to do, and what it did instead.

Answer (score 2):

Sikuli built-in OCR features are pretty buggy and unstable. All (or at least most of) the related issues are listed in [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/sikuli/+bug/710586) BUG. However there are few possible workarounds which are, however, not also always applicable..

1. If the text is known, you can take a screenshot of the text and then look for it **as a screenshot**. For example if you know exact font of this text, you can automatically generate such text on the screen and use it as a pattern to locate it elsewhere.
2. The built-in [tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) based OCR, performs significantly better when the font is bigger, "fatter" and in Grayscale (usually). Hence you might do some background image processing before attempting the actual recognition. I used [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to resize and filter the images for better recognition. It can be in the background as a command line tool. For example:

   convert  -filter spline -resize 100x -unsharp 10x20 -type Grayscale

I am aware that this does not answer your question directly but these are steps you might consider taking towards the final solution.

Comment: well this is not the answer but thank you anyway, I'll try playing with Sikuli and your advices might help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer at Deskover company and we are currently developing an application, [UiPath Studio](http://uipath.com/) that meets your needs.

We provide text recognition on various technologies with 100% accuracy, ability to find specific text in an area on screen, a control or an entire window, and also ability to click text or controls.

You can execute different actions, sequentially by creating workflows.

We at Deskover are big fans of Sikuli project. We actually use the same image recognition engine in UiPath Studio.

UiPath Studio is a visual tool that helps you create workflows easily, but you can also use the underlying API and implement an application that extracts text and clicks on it.
You can find more details about the UiPath library [here](http://doc.uipath.com/).